# Is there a way to route all traffic from Android through a proxy/tunnel to my Tomato router?

Tags: vpn, encryption

I'd like to be able to connect my Android phone to public Wi-Fi points (some with unencrypted connections), but:

1. People can see what I'm doing by intercepting unencrypted radio transmissions
2. The AP owner or [other people logged into it](https://superuser.com/q/156869/13889) can [see what I'm doing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep)
3. Hackers can pretend to be the access point and carry out [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

There are tools like [Wi-Fi Ruler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hogdex.WifiRuler&hl=en) and [WeFi](http://www.wefi.com) to automatically connect to access points, but I don't trust random APs.  I'd like all my traffic to go through an encrypted tunnel to my home router, and from there out to the Internet.

I've done such tunnels from other computers with [SSH/SOCKS](http://lifehacker.com/237227/geek-to-live--encrypt-your-web-browsing-session-with-an-ssh-socks-proxy) and [PPTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol) before.  Is there any way to do this with Android?

More specifically:

- My phone now has [CyanogenMod 7.1.0](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/)
- My router currently has [TomatoUSB Version 1.28](http://tomatousb.org/)

I'm willing to change the router firmware, but I was having issues with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) disconnecting, which is why I'm using Tomato.  Some possible solutions:

SSH with [dynamic SOCKS proxy](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/449):

- Android supposedly supports this through [ConnectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/), but I don't know how to get it to route *all* traffic.
- Tomato supports this natively.

I've been using this with [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) for my web browsing at work.  Requires setting up each app to go through the proxy, though.

PPTP:

- Android supports this natively.
- Tomato does not support this, unless you get the [jyavenard mod](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showpost.php?p=336696&postcount=28) and compile it?

I [previously used PPTP](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/PPTP_Server_Configuration) for web browsing at work and in China because it's native in Windows and DD-WRT.  After a while I started having problems with it, then I started having problems with DD-WRT, so I switched to the SSH tunnel instead.  Also it supposedly has security flaws, but I don't understand how big of a problem it is.

IPSec L2TP:

- Android (phone) and Windows (work/China) both support this natively
- I don't know of a router that does.  I could [run it on my computer using openswan](http://rootmanager.com/ubuntu-ipsec-l2tp-windows-domain-auth/setting-up-openswan-xl2tpd-with-native-windows-clients.html), but then there are two points of failure.

OpenVPN:

- CyanogenMod [apparently includes this](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=347), and now has an entry to create a new OpenVPN in the normal VPN interface, but I have no idea [how to configure it](http://github.com/fries/android-external-openvpn/blob/master/README).

  - [TunnelDroid](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tunneldroid) apparently handles some of this.
  - Future versions will have [native support in the VPN settings](http://code.google.com/p/cyanogenmod/issues/detail?id=1036)?
- Tomato does not support this, but there are mods that do?  I don't know how to configure this, either.

  - [TomatoVPN](http://tomatovpn.keithmoyer.com/)
  - [roadkill mod](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showthread.php?t=53233)
  - [SgtPepperKSU mod](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showthread.php?t=59416)
  - [Thor mod](http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showthread.php?t=61552)

I could also run a VPN server on my desktop, I guess, though that's less reliable and presumably slower than running it in the router itself.  I could change the router firmware, but I'm wary of more fundamental things breaking.  Tomato has been problem-free for the regular stuff.

Related: [Anyone set up a SSH tunnel to their (rooted) G1 for browsing?](http://androidcommunity.com/forums/f28/anyone-set-up-a-ssh-tunnel-to-their-rooted-g1-for-browsing-11297/)

Answer (score 4):

You can configure android to use a proxy server. But you must do it either from the adb client, or from the terminal in a rooted g1.

1. > adb shell
2. # sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
3. sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', 'proxy:port');
4. sqlite>.exit

read about @ http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2008/01/set-proxy-for-android-web-browser.html

Comment: This is just for the stock Android web browser, right?  I want every communication from any app to be tunneled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) to tunnel your connection over SSH.

Comment: Really?  I know how to use Connectbot to log into an SSH server, but how do I configure it to tunnel everything through that connection?

Comment: I use it sometimes with android-vnc-viewer, check FAQ question #8:
http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/wiki/faq

"...We recommend you tunnel your VNC connection over SSH with connectbot. Set up your connectbot connection to the server hosting your VNC server, and configure a tunnel to forward port 5900. Then you can set up an android-vnc-viewer connection to 5900 on localhost..."

Something similar can be done to tunnel especific data.

Comment: Ah, cool.  That doesn't cover sending *everything* over the SSH tunnel, though.  I asked the same question over here:  http://www.forceclose.com/questions/369/is-there-a-way-to-route-all-traffic-from-android-through-a-secure-tunnel  Maybe you want to add your answer?

Comment: I just added :D

Comment: That FAQ says "configure a tunnel to forward port 5900", but it doesn't tell how to do that.

Comment: in ConnectBot's Hosts lists:
- Long press on a user@host line.
- Edit port forwards.
- menu
- Add port forward.
- Complete the form.

Comment: There's also https://market.android.com/details?id=org.sshtunnel but I'm not sure if it tunnels everythinI.

Comment: @endolith this should be part of this answer...